# UITableView: selected cell color is not rendered in ios13

Tags: ios13

I'm using Xcode 11 beta 6, on selecting the UITableViewcell ,cell has not been highlighted.It has a white background instead of showing selected background color.

Answer (score 22):

Per iOS 13 release notes (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_ipados_13_beta_8_release_notes) - The UITableViewCell class no longer changes the backgroundColor or isOpaque properties of the contentView and any of its subviews when cells become highlighted or selected.

> The UITableViewCell class no longer changes the backgroundColor or isOpaque properties of the contentView and any of its subviews when cells become highlighted or selected. If you are setting an opaque backgroundColor on any subviews of the cell inside (and including) the contentView, the appearance when the cell becomes highlighted or selected might be affected. The simplest way to resolve any issues with your subviews is to ensure their backgroundColor is set to nil or clear, and their opaque property is false. However, if needed you can override the setHighlighted(*:animated:) and setSelected(*:animated:) methods to manually change these properties on your subviews when moving to or from the highlighted and selected states.

Comment: Relevant for 13.1.2. Would be nice to know why this change happened. Pretty sure a bunch of devs like me would feel frustrated for some short time figuring out what happened to their selection color

Comment: @rommex To me it seems like this helps adapting your UI to Dark Mode more easily. I don't know for sure; I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me for iOS13 device that build with Xcode11.1

**Objective-c**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

   cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

}
```

**Swift**

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me.

1. I had to assign clearColor to contentView of my cell.

   `cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`
2. Then assign a background view to cell when selected. I added below code in my `cellForRowAt:` method:

   ```
   UIView *test = [[UIView alloc] init];

   test.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:213.0f/255.0f green:239.0f/255.0f blue:222.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

   your_Cell.selectedBackgroundView = test;
   ```